# Error converting a string to a int to convert media time to minutes and seconds

Tags: java, android, time

Please my apk was working fine taking the time information for media song and sudendly started to generate an error with the int variable at y the moment it converts the string variable in a int to calculate the time in minutes and seconds. This this the error¨

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.musicplayer, PID: 17390
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.musicplayer/com.example.musicplayer.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: s == null
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2053)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: s == null
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:570)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:643)
        at com.example.musicplayer.MainActivity.getSongTitle(MainActivity.java:655)
        at com.example.musicplayer.MainActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(MainActivity.java:689)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:7854)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7705)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5037)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5084) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2053) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 17390 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

the code is the following:

```
public void getSongTitle() {

  int Time1 = 0;
  //retrieve song info
    ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);
    if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){
        //get columns
        int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        int timeColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION);
        int time1Column = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION);

        do {
            long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
            String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
            String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
            String thisTime = musicCursor.getString(timeColumn);
            String thisTime1 = ("");

            Time1 = Integer.parseInt(thisTime)/1000;
            double min = Math.floor(Time1/60);
            double sec = (Time1 -min*60);

            //thisTime1 = (""+min);
            if (min<10) {
                if (sec<10) {
                    thisTime1 =("0"+Math.round(min)+":0"+Math.round(sec));
                }else{
                    thisTime1 =("0"+Math.round(min)+":"+Math.round(sec));
                }
            }else {
                if (sec<10) {
                    thisTime1 =(""+Math.round(min)+":0"+Math.round(sec));
                } else {
                    thisTime1 =(""+Math.round(min)+":"+Math.round(sec));
                }
            }

            songList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist, thisTime, thisTime1));

        }
        while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

`at com.example.musicplayer.MainActivity.getSongTitle(MainActivity.java:655)` IS the LINE `Time1 = Integer.parseInt(thisTime)/1000;`

```
    com.example.musicplayer.MainActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(MainActivity.java:689) IS WHEN I CALL THE METHOD
```

Comment: The important bit is `java.lang.NumberFormatException: s == null at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:570)` ==> `musicCursor.getString(timeColumn)` is `null`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)